# Google reCaptcha v2 (Checkbox) Verification

Tags: php, html, json

I have a contact form which is working fine. I have Integrate Google ReCaptcha v2 with it and it is showing below my contact form but form will be submitted either user checked reCaptcha or not. I want to verify it that form only goes submit if user has checked google ReCaptcha otherwise it shows a message to the user to check it.

Here is my HTML Form (contact.html):

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer>
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <form action="contact_us.php" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Your 
         Name *" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email *" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" name="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Contact Number">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <textarea class="form-control textarea" name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="g-recaptcha" data sitekey="have_enter_my_site_key_here"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" class="form-control btn- 
           submit" Value="Send">
    </div>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is PHP code as (contact_us.php):

```php
<?php
  ob_start();
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $phone = $_POST['phone'];
  $message = $_POST['message'];

  $email_from ='';
  $email_subject = "Contact Form";
  $email_body = "User Name: $name \n".
    "User Email: $email \n".
    "Phone Number: $phone \n".
    "User Message: \n $message \n";

  $to = "my_Email_here";

  $headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
  $headers = "Reply-To: $email \r\n";

  $result = mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);

  if($result) {
    echo "Sent Successfully";
  }

  else{
    echo "Something Went wrong. Please try again";
  }
?>
```

Help me how should I verify google ReCaptcha with my HTML form.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']) && !empty($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])) {
    // Your site secret key obtained from Google
    $secret         = '#####################################';
    $grResponse     = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
    // Verify with Google Servers
    $verifyResponse = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=' . $secret . '&response=' . $grResponse);
    $responseData   = json_decode($verifyResponse);
    if ($responseData->success) {
        ob_start();
        $name    = $_POST['name'];
        $email   = $_POST['email'];
        $phone   = $_POST['phone'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];

        $email_from    = '';
        $email_subject = "Contact Form";
        $email_body    = "User Name: $name \n" . "User Email: $email \n" . "Phone Number: $phone \n" . "User Message: \n $message \n";

        $to = "my_Email_here";

        $headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
        $headers = "Reply-To: $email \r\n";

        $result = mail($to, $email_subject, $email_body, $headers);

        if ($result) {
            echo "Sent Successfully";
        }

        else {
           echo "Something Went wrong. Please try again";
        }
    } else {
         echo "################################"; 
    }
} else {

       echo "################################"; 
} 
?>
```

Please check below code: